# Is it wrong to use a comment tag as the end of a div?

Tags: html, tags, comments

Is it a bad practice or has a negative effect to use a **comment tag as the end of a div**, not using a ">" to close it?

```html
<div class="container"> 

  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

</div <!--container-->
```

I find it more readable this way, rather than closing a div and opening a comment on the same line.

Comment: That tag is not actually closed, so yes, it is wrong in this example. Have you found this to actually work in practice?

Comment: Yes, it works like a regular comment tag, and it didn't cause any problems so far. But I haven't seen it on any others projects, so it feels kinda odd

Comment: The comment tag is absolutely fine, I was talking about the unclosed `</div>` tag, which would surely cause issues.

Comment: Your div now is not closed so yew it will affect for sure

Comment: Actually, it didn't cause any trouble to use them as showed, it seems like the comment tag closes the div.

Comment: I actually went ahead and did some tests of my own, including nested elements, and checked it with developer tools and apparently it actually works, even though it is syntactically incorrect. It really works and I hate it. Everything I thought I knew about HTML was a lie.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty weird but works just fine. Still don't know if I should use it or not, it may trigger some web devs, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what the spec says an HTML5-compliant parser should do ([W3C HTML5.2§8.2.4.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#end-tag-open-state), [WHATWG HTML§13.2.5.7](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#end-tag-open-state)), this should behave identically to a proper end tag.

But it's a syntax error. And syntax errors are called errors for a reason. Whether you think it's bad practice to do this depends entirely on whether you think it's bad practice to rely on syntax errors with known, fixed behaviors, or writing syntax errors is bad practice in the first place.

Comment: Actual specs are at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#end-tag-open-state

Comment: @Kaiido: You say that like I'm not aware. But I did get distracted and forget to add that in (you can tell I was going to by the fact that it says "W3C HTML5.2").

Comment: I just say that as if I found a link to a superseded specs which is now outdated in an answer posted yesterday. Nothing more, I know what it is to post answers I know that navigating through many tabs may make us copy the wrong links sometimes. Just wanna help.

Answer (score 1):

Is it wrong? Yes, very.

Does it work? Somehow, yes.

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div <!--container1-->
<div class="container2" style="background-color:blue"> 
  <h2>Hello Again!</h2 <!-- what happens when I do it here? -->
  <div class="container" <!-- or here -->
        <h3 style="color:white;">Hello Nested!</h3 <!-- eh, why not?-->
        <p>some text, maybe some <b>bold text</b <!-- this is anarchy-->, more text, <i>italicized text</i <!-- wow --></p <!------------------>
        <p>another paragraph</p>

  </div <!--container nested-->
    <script>
        console.log('ughhh');
    </script <!--please god no, why? how?-->

</div <!--container2-->
```

So yes, it does work and I hate it

Comment: m a s t e r p i e c e